# How to prove that the hermite polynomials are a Appell sequence?

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis, hermite-polynomials

The hermite polynomials I am saying is defined by the recursive relation $f_{n+1}(x)=2xf_n(x)-f_n'(x)$ with $f_0=1$. I need to prove that they have the relation $f'_n(x)=2nf_{n-1}(x)$. I tried everything I know but cannot prove this relation. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Have you tried using induction? Assume that $f_n$ satisfies $f_n' = 2nf_{n-1}$, and then show that $f_{n+1}' = 2(n+1) f_n$.